# Bug in stat_summary with scale_y_log10 in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I'm aggregating and plotting:

```
d <- # set d to the database below.

agg <- aggregate(wt ~ t, data=d, FUN=mean)

# example 1
ggplot(agg, aes(x=t, y=wt)) + geom_line(size = 1.5)

# example 1log
ggplot(agg, aes(x=t, y=wt)) + geom_line(size = 1.5) + scale_y_log10()

# example 2
ggplot(d, aes(x=t, y=wt)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", size = 1.5)

# example 2log
ggplot(d, aes(x=t, y=wt)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", size = 1.5) + 
    scale_y_log10()
```

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

Example 2log:

[image: Example 2log]

The problem is that even though example 1 and 2 are equal, example 1log and 2log are different and example 2log is even not consistent with example 2 at all.

Am I doing something wrong or this a bug?

I need to use the example 2log because I want to aggregate with different conditions, e.g.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=t, y=wt)) +
  stat_summary(data=subset(data, dim == 6 & maxt == 32 & max_trials == 10000 & t > 2), fun.y="mean", geom="line", color="black", size = 1.5) + 
  stat_summary(data=subset(data, dim == 6 & maxt == 16 & max_trials == 1000 & t > 2), fun.y="mean", geom="line", color="black", size = 1.5) + scale_y_log10()
```

This is the dataset I'm using and that reproduces the error, as exported by `write.table(d, "test.dat")`:

```
"wt" "t"
"7" 12 3
"9" 18 4
"11" 28 6
"13" 14 7
"15" 81 9
"21" 97 10
"23" 3 11
"25" 12 12
"28" 46 13
"35" 1296 15
"37" 63 16
"39" 43 17
"41" 88 18
"43" 395 19
"45" 512 20
"47" 154 21
"49" 9 22
"51" 83 23
"53" 5 24
"55" 1606 25
"57" 3838 26
"59" 1331 27
"74" 23 3
"76" 20 4
"81" 79 5
"83" 32 6
"85" 14 7
"88" 24 8
"89" 9 9
"93" 67 10
"97" 44 11
"98" 18 12
"99" 101 13
"100" 17 14
"101" 19 16
"102" 41 18
"103" 9 19
"105" 26 20
"108" 76 21
"109" 2 22
"113" 883 23
"116" 2054 24
"137" 16 3
"139" 26 4
"140" 4 5
"144" 15 6
"145" 5 7
"150" 31 8
"155" 49 11
"168" 5700 12
"173" 12 3
"176" 40 6
"181" 89 7
"182" 2 8
"183" 4 9
"184" 5 10
"186" 35 11
"194" 357 12
"195" 13 13
"208" 2544 14
"209" 83 15
"210" 168 16
"211" 313 17
"212" 7 18
"213" 48 19
"214" 18 20
"215" 3 21
"216" 35 22
"230" 9 3
"233" 23 4
"235" 60 5
"236" 8 6
"237" 5 7
"238" 23 8
"239" 10 9
"240" 28 10
"241" 8 11
"242" 31 12
"244" 22 13
"245" 12 14
"246" 2 15
"247" 9 16
"261" 3475 17
"266" 1091 18
"267" 53 19
"268" 13 20
"269" 40 22
"270" 264 26
"271" 1726 27
"292" 43 3
"294" 22 4
"301" 48 5
"306" 81 6
"307" 5 7
"308" 25 8
"309" 12 9
"311" 12 10
"315" 63 13
"316" 2 14
"317" 30 15
```

Comment: I think in your second example you are plotting the mean of log10 `wt` rather than mean `wt` on the log10 scale.  This sentence from the help page for `coord_trans` may help explain what is happening: `The difference between transforming the scales and  transforming the coordinate system is that scale transformation occurs BEFORE statistics, and coordinate transformation afterwards.`

Comment: @aosmith, you are right. Could you answer the question so it can be useful to others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with when the transformation occurs when using transformations via `scale_y_*`.  A helpful note is in the help page of `coord_trans`, which says:

> The difference between transforming the scales and transforming the
>   coordinate system is that scale transformation occurs BEFORE
>   statistics, and coordinate transformation afterwards.

Because the transforming happens before the statistics you are calculating via `stat_summary`, your plot `2log` is a plot of the mean of `log10(wt)` rather than `mean(wt)` on the log10 scale.  You can verify this by calculating the mean of `log10(wt)` for each level of `t` before graphing.

```
agg2 <- aggregate(log(wt) ~ t, data=d, FUN=mean)

ggplot(agg2, aes(x=t, y=`log(wt)`)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1.5)
```

The shape of the line is the same as in `2log`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem. I think that the combination of `stat_summary` and the different y scale behaves suspiciously.

I've created a simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(t=c(1,1,10,10,30,30), wt = c(1,1,20,180,1200,1200))


ggplot(data, aes(x=t, y=wt)) +
  stat_summary(data=data, 
               fun.y="mean", geom="line", color="black", size = 1.5)+
  scale_y_log10()


d <- aggregate(wt ~ t, data=data, FUN=mean)

ggplot(d, aes(x=t, y=wt)) + geom_line(size = 1.5) + scale_y_log10()
```

The plots I get are:

[image]
[image]

Also, if you run the above process without the `scale_y_log10` you'll get exactly the same plots.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the question with a complete minimal example that reproduces the problem. Unfortunately I believe it behaves worst than suspiciously.